# Unable to start ntpd.service

Tags: ntp

First, I installed the `ntp` package through `sudo apt-get install ntp`

I accessed `/etc/ntp.conf` to change the servers to a few local ones based on country, then I saved and restarted it using `sudo systemctl restart ntp` then checked the status with `sudo systemctl status ntp` which is shown running.

I also did `ntpq -p` which gave the below result, I think this means the client is running:

```
    remote          refid   st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 ntp.ubuntu.com  .POOL.         16 p    -   64  0   0.000   0.000   0.000
*time-a-g.nist.g .NIST.         1 u -   64   77   11.567   -7.287   7.636
-174.138.107.37  46.243.26.34   2 u   63   64   37   84.975 0.159   4.474
-ns3.weiszhostin 128.138.141.172  2 u   1   64   77   69.844  -11.884   6.043
+li290-38.member 128.138.141.172  2 u   65   64   37   43.448   -3.202   6.023
+pugot.canonical 145.238.203.14   2 u   61   64   37   79.540   -5.833   4.040
+alphyn.canonica 132.246.11.231   2 u   4   64   77   11.714   -5.017   7.244
+chilipepper.can 145.238.203.14   2 u   61   64   37   78.136   -4.269   4.769
+golem.canonical 145.238.203.14   2 u   55   64   37   81.139   -3.766   4.748
```

However, I can't seem to get the daemon to run. I found that out when I did `sudo systemctl status ntpd`, then it gave the below result:

```
ntpd.service 
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

I thought it was not started at first so I did `sudo systemctl start ntpd`, but it gave:

`Failed to start ntpd.service: Unit ntpd.service not found.`

That's when I found out something is seriously wrong, I checked `ls -l /etc/init.d` and found only `ntp` is in the list, `ntpd` can't be found. I also tried to reinstall `ntp` but that didn't help.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not using `ntp` but you can try `ntpq` instead of `ntpd` above.

Answer (score 9):

It was an issue for a long time on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. It was enabled, but inactive, so I'd had to start it manually after every reboot.

```
$ sudo systemctl status ntp.service

● ntp.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:ntpd(8)
```

The reason was in conflict with service **systemd-timesyncd.service**, and it's a part of systemd. After I disabled it ntp.service began to start successfully.

```
$ sudo systemctl show ntp.service | grep Conflicts
Conflicts=shutdown.target systemd-timesyncd.service
$ sudo systemctl status  systemd-timesyncd.service
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-07-12 05:17:21 UTC; 18min ago
$ dpkg -S /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service
systemd: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service
$ sudo systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd.service
Removed /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-timesyncd.service.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install -y ntp
sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
sudo service ntp restart
sudo service ntp status | cat
```

Comment: wow if someone googles a similar kind of questions / tries to read this answer and he/she does not know what sudo apt-get install and sudo service do ... a short explanation won't help him in THIS context ...

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo systemctl unmask ntp.service
sudo systemctl start ntp.service
sudo systemctl enable ntp.service
```

Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS the `ntp` package contain:

1. client and utilites - `/usr/bin/calc_tickadj`, `/usr/bin/ntpdc`, `/usr/bin/ntpq`, `/usr/bin/ntpsweep`, `/usr/bin/ntptrace`, `/usr/bin/update-leap`.
2. daemon (`/usr/sbin/ntpd`), started by `/etc/init.d/ntp`.

You may restart the service with

```
sudo systemctl restart ntp.service
```

or

```
sudo service ntp restart
```

You can check that server is running with

```
sudo service ntp status
sudo systemctl status ntp.service
sudo netstat -pl | grep ntp
```

on my system it returns:

```
$ sudo netstat -pl | grep ntp
udp        0      0 10.0.2.15:ntp           *:*             12303/ntpd      
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           *:*             12303/ntpd      
udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*             12303/ntpd      
udp6       0      0 fe80::99a2:45db:62e:ntp [::]:*          12303/ntpd      
udp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:ntp       [::]:*          12303/ntpd      
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*          12303/ntp
```

And it was started by systemd:

```
$ pstree -l -s -p -a 12303
systemd,1 splash
  └─ntpd,12303 -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 121:129

$ ps -P 12303
  PID PSR TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
12303   0 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 121:129
```

Comment: So `ntp` is both a client and a daemon? I am able to start `ntp` but can't start `ntpd`, I can use the man page, it's just that `ntpd.service` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, it contain both. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS man page [`man ntpd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/ntpd.8.html) does not refer to `ntpd.service`.

Answer (score 0):

NTP is a peer to peer protocol, so the `ntpd` daemon acts as both server and client at the same time.

On Ubuntu, the service is named `ntp` even though the daemon is named `ntpd`.
If you look at the output of `sudo systemctl status ntp` you'll see that it actually runs `ntpd`:

```
   CGroup: /system.slice/ntp.service
           └─1201 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 110:118
```

So everything is fine. `systemctl` shows the `ntpd` daemon is running, and `ntpq -p` shows it's synchronizing successfully to other servers.