# Can't sync time to network server on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, time, ntp

Upgraded to 19.10 a three weeks ago, and since then, I can't get the system to sync with a time server.

What I've done:

```
xxxx@asgard:~$ cat /etc/timezone
America/Los_Angeles
marc@asgard:~$ timedatectl
               Local time: Tue 2020-01-14 15:18:24 PST
           Universal time: Tue 2020-01-14 23:18:24 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2020-01-14 23:18:27
                Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PST, -0800)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
xxxx@asgard:~$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd.service
[sudo] password for xxxx: 
xxxx@asgard:~$ timedatectl
               Local time: Tue 2020-01-14 15:19:13 PST
           Universal time: Tue 2020-01-14 23:19:13 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2020-01-14 23:19:16
                Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PST, -0800)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
xxxx@asgard:~$ sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
xxxx@asgard:~$ timedatectl
               Local time: Tue 2020-01-14 15:19:44 PST
           Universal time: Tue 2020-01-14 23:19:44 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2020-01-14 23:19:47
                Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PST, -0800)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Any hints?

Comment: " NTP service: inactive"  suggests https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009729/unable-to-start-ntpd-service would be useful.

Comment: I think the hint by @K7AAY is right, but for older systemd where ntpd was used. That would today be chrony, yet for just the client portion systemd-timesyncd should be enough. Enabling ought to be `timedatectl set-ntp 1` maybe then followed by `timedatectl timesync-status` and `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`. There are environments (e.g. in containers) where the service will just not start due to the condition of being in a container. That should be in that data, therefore reporting such info here by updating the question might also help

Comment: Marc W. Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons that appear just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: This type of issue could also be caused by restrictive [firewall settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163409): make sure your firewall allows outbound UDP traffic on port 123

Answer (score 4):

This problem occurs because of a conflict between `ntp.service` and `systemd-timesyncd.service`. It's a known bug.

Why does this happen? It occurs on systems that have been upgraded to 19.10. `ntp.service` is carried over during an upgrade, and 19.10's `systemd-timesyncd.server` won't start in its presence.

`more /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d/disable-with-time-daemon.conf`

```
[Unit]
# don't run timesyncd if we have another NTP daemon installed
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/ntpd
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/openntpd
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/chronyd
ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService
```

See the following:

`systemctl status  ntp.service`

```
● ntp.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-01-15 11:05:12 PST; 1h 21min ago
     Docs: man:ntpd(8)
 Main PID: 28740 (ntpd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 2.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/ntp.service
           └─28740 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 120:131

Jan 15 11:15:30 Satellite-E55 ntpd[28740]: 184.105.182.7 local addr 192.168.0.10
Jan 15 11:16:28 Satellite-E55 ntpd[28740]: 198.58.105.63 local addr 192.168.0.10
Jan 15 11:17:38 Satellite-E55 ntpd[28740]: 69.10.161.7 local addr 192.168.0.100 
Jan 15 11:17:39 Satellite-E55 ntpd[28740]: 66.172.17.62 local addr 192.168.0.100
Jan 15 11:28:55 Satellite-E55 ntpd[28740]: 172.98.193.44 local addr 192.168.0.10
Jan 15 11:28:57 Satellite-E55 ntpd[28740]: 45.33.2.219 local addr 192.168.0.100 
Jan 15 11:29:20 Satellite-E55 ntpd[28740]: 91.189.94.4 local addr 192.168.0.100 
Jan 15 11:29:55 Satellite-E55 ntpd[28740]: 216.229.0.49 local addr 192.168.0.100
Jan 15 11:31:07 Satellite-E55 ntpd[28740]: 74.6.168.73 local addr 192.168.0.100 
Jan 15 11:31:08 Satellite-E55 ntpd[28740]: 69.195.142.11 local addr 192.168.0.10
```

`systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service`

```
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; disabled; vend
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
           └─disable-with-time-daemon.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)

Jan 15 07:52:09 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Ti
Jan 15 07:52:11 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Ti
Jan 15 07:52:13 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Ti
Jan 15 07:52:23 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Ti
Jan 15 07:52:24 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Ti
Jan 15 07:52:57 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Ti
Jan 15 07:52:58 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Ti
Jan 15 07:53:00 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Ti
Jan 15 07:54:00 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Ti
Jan 15 07:59:57 Satellite-E55 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Ti
```

One visual side effect of this problem can be seen in the `Date & Time` settings panel. You can't enable "Automatic Date & Time". The switch flips back to disabled.

[image]

However, `ntp` still does the time synchronization with the various ntp servers.

This *can* be fixed by uninstalling `ntp`, `ntpdate`, and `sntp`, and letting `systemd-timesyncd.service` perform the time synchronization.

**Sources:**

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1858095

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1848309

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1849156