# How do I solve Internet Time Sync Not Happening?

Tags: sync, ubuntu-mate, time, ntp, timezone

Searched through some places and did a lot of stuff. I have tried [Unable to start ntpd.service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009729/), [How do I set time and date from the Internet?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79112/how-do-i-set-time-and-date-from-the-internet) and also tried [chrony](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/environment-ntp-controller.html).

I saw more places, as far as I recall. Don't know if am doing something wrong.

Look:
[image]

`/etc/ntp.conf` content:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

# Leap seconds definition provided by tzdata
leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list

# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

# Specify one or more NTP servers.

# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board
# on 2011-02-08 (LP: #104525). See http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html for
# more information.
pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst

# Use Ubuntu's ntp server as a fallback.
pool ntp.ubuntu.com

# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Needed for adding pool entries
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust


# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
#broadcastclient

#Changes recquired to use pps synchonisation as explained in documentation:
#http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-config-adv.htm#AEN3918

#server 127.127.8.1 mode 135 prefer    # Meinberg GPS167 with PPS
#fudge 127.127.8.1 time1 0.0042        # relative to PPS for my hardware

#server 127.127.22.1                   # ATOM(PPS)
#fudge 127.127.22.1 flag3 1            # enable PPS API
```

Comment: Just so it's clearer guys: on the screenshot, it's 00:29:28 as local time, when it should show on my system 03:29:28! It's actually doing it wrong. For example: BRT is now 11:52 AM (which is the same as São Paulo that follows). It should show, on system clock, the time but was shown as 08:52 AM when I wrote.

Comment: Also, I have a dual boot to Windows 10 (for MS OFFICE) (and other possibilities).

Comment: Windows' time, and machine Setup's time are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Done! Finally!

Done: timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock

Also check (as was known) timedtectl shows us that I do use local time zone; then, rebooted. Checked and Windows time keeps fine. Up to Mate back again. Works!

Anyhow, appreciate the post from the following [blog](https://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/como-corrigir-diferencas-de-tempo-entre-o-ubuntu-e-o-windows-em-sistema-com-dual-boot/).

Appreciate you all who thought on helping out! See ya!